# Issue in integrating ANTLR4 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, antlr

I tried to integrate ANTLR4 in Visual Studio by referring the information from the [link](http://programming-pages.com/2013/12/14/antlr-4-with-c-and-visual-studio-2012/).

I added below mentioned code in .csproj file based on the above mentioned link.

```
    <PropertyGroup>
       <!-- Folder containing Antlr4BuildTasks.dll -->
      <Antlr4BuildTaskPath>$(ProjectDir)..\Reference\Antlr4</Antlr4BuildTaskPath>
      <!-- Path to the ANTLR Tool itself. -->
      <Antlr4ToolPath>$(ProjectDir)..\Reference\Antlr4\antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar</Antlr4ToolPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(ProjectDir)..\Reference\Antlr4\Antlr4.targets" />
```

After editing the .csproj file, I tried to reload the project. It throwing the error saying that **"The imported project "..\Reference\Antlr4\Antlr4.targets" was not found."**

Then I looked into the folder **\Reference\Antlr4** , but it not contains **Antlr4.targets** file. I downloaded **Antlr4.Runtime.dll** and **antlr-4.5.1-complete.jar** from ANTLR site but I cannot find Antlr4.targets.

Please help me how to find the **Antlr4.targets** file.

Thanks,
Siva.

Answer (score -1):

That blog post seems to be ANTLR 3 based (though it claims to be 4). You might check mine instead,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2014/08/how-to-use-antlr-4-on-net/

The targets file should come from the NuGet packages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I will check that :)